# Type switch on controller

Tags: go, revel

I'm implementing a simple interceptor using revel, who's sole responsibility is to ensure that a user is authenticated and redirect to auth page if not. I have something to the effect of

```
func setUser(c *revel.Controller) revel.Result {
    switch interface{}(c.Type).(type) {
    case controllers.Auth:
        return nil
    }
    return c.Redirect(controllers.Auth.Index)
}
```

The type case `controllers.Auth` is never encountered, effectively resulting in an infinite loop. I'm assuming there's something obvious I'm missing, but while I figure out how to run a revel app through gdb to try and debug this, figured I'd ask here.

Answer (score 2):

I believe for your switch you need a base case. You end up in it infinitely because c's type is not `controllers.Auth` and you have no other cases. But, in your use case, there is no reason to use a switch and I personally wouldn't. It's binary, so just type assert on `controllers.Auth`, if it's not that then you redirect.

```
func setUser(c *revel.Controller) revel.Result {
    if _, ok := c.(controllers.Auth); ok {
             return c.Redirect(controllers.Auth.Index)   
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work as-is. `err` apparently isn't part of the return data (it's a `bool` now). `c` is `$3 = (struct github.com/revel/revel.Controller *) 0xc20805b130 (gdb)`, which doesn't upcast to `controllers.Auth` (still get the same infinite loop). I've been able to just do a simple check on the controller `.Name` attribute, but it just seems a little wrong to me that I can't do this same thing through type assertions. Maybe something in the revel underpinnings that I haven't dug through yet..

Comment: @DemianBrecht yeah, sorry little mistake with error as the second return type instead of `bool`. I don't entirely follow your comment though, with the code after my edit, it doesn't do what you want?

Comment: Nah, unfortunately it doesn't and I have to get a little more familiar with both the type system and how revel instantiates controllers to speak to it more authoritatively. It /seems/ like the controller passed in doesn't pass the type assertion, even when the Name attribute is as expected. I see that revel instantiates controllers using reflection, so perhaps there's something there that's causing the type assertion to fail.

Comment: @DemianBrecht I'd have to look into `revel` myself a bit to provide further guidance but at the high level, `c` is not of type `controllers.Auth` so this code is working as expected, it's just the type isn't what you expected. As a test you might want to import reflect and print the type out here. I was assuming `Controller` is an interface and the actual type would be `controllers.Auth`

Comment: @DemianBrecht oh one other thing that just came to mind... If `Controller` is in fact an interface, then passing it by value may solve your problem. I would also want to read a little bit before making any statement about why this is however in most cases you want to avoid pointer to interface in Go.